# Android ListView - Change active item's text's color

Tags: android, listview

I'd like to create a custom effect on my ListView in Android. I have a list with text items - a kind a menu. And I'd like to change the text's color (and add a shadow for it!), when the Android changes the background under the list element.

I've a custom view (wich extends the TextView), where I overrided the `onTouchEvent()` function, and created a function, which changes the text's color back.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    Log.v(TAG, "" + event.getAction());
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        Log.v(TAG, "Touch started.");
        setShadowLayer(6, 0, 0, getResources().getColor(R.color.selectedTextShadow));
        setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.selectedTextColor));
        boolean b = super.onTouchEvent(event);
        Log.v(TAG, "Action down, super returns: " + (b ? "true" : "false"));
        //return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void endSelection(){
    setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
    setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
}
```

And in the ListFragment I override the `onListItemClick()` function, to call the `endSelection` function of the view.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    Log.v(TAG, "Clicked on: " + position);
    ((ListRowText) v.findViewById(R.id.subMenuRow_menuItem)).endSelection();
}
```

It's almost perdect. But (as you can see it in [this](http://youtu.be/v5mXbKvZhWo) video), it does not change back the color, when I "swipe" my finger somewhere else, and the color "stucks".

Is there a better way, to do this?
I've found the [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)s, but I cannot add a shadow for StateListDrawable. Or can I?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Patty P said you can just create a state selector but in your case I think what you want is a text selector.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

You simply create a folder called color in your res folder and you can add selectors just like in the case of the list selector.

You can then use it as text color.

## android:textColor="@color/mystatelist"

The states are the same

Answer (score 0):

Clean looking UI by the way. You'll probably want to take a look at Android Asset Studios' [Holo colors generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/) and generate a list selector to get a look at all the events that are being tracked on touch. For your individual list item views you may want to make a separate state list drawable for just the text view and style it according with your list selector. Here is a list of states that the generated selector handles:

- state_window_focused=false
- state_focused=true  &&  state_enabled=false && state_pressed=true
- state_focused=true  &&  state_enabled=false
- state_focused=true  &&  state_pressed=true
- state_focused=false &&  state_pressed=true
- state_focused=true